# DynamoDB access to items inside a dictionary

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am starting using dynamoDB with python, and I have a doubt I can't find an answer online. I have a JSON with this format:

```
{
"version": "1.0.0",
"trips":[
       {
        "paymentMode": "ONLINE",
        "type":"A",
        "locations":{
            "name": "Zona A",
            "payment":1000
            "company": ["XXX", "YYY"]

        },
        
       {
        "paymentMode": "CASH",
        "type":"B",
        "locations":{
            "name": "Zona D",
            "payment":200
            "company": ["XXX", "YYY"]
        }
    ]
}
```

I can store it like that directly but I don't know if there is a way I can access individually each of the elements in trips in a get_item operation or similar? Like, having for example paymentMode and type as primary and sort key, even if they are inside the field "trips".

The input will be a Json like this, but I would like to put those fields as PK (considering they are unique) so I can retrieve only one item.

I know you can just scan everything and then iterate trips, but maybe with more elements, it will take too long. Is there a way to do this directly? if so, how can I do it? does dynamoDb do this automatically or i have to name it like trips.PaymentMode or something like that?

Thank you very much

Comment: You need to understand data modeling with DynamoDB. There are a number of resources available online, for example AWS re:Invent 2020: Data modeling with Amazon DynamoDB [part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fiP2e-g-r4g) and [part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0uLF1tjI_BI).

Comment: yeah, I need to learn more about it, but I cant find if  I can't choose as Partition Key, something inside a filed in a JSON (like paymentMode, considering it is unique). The input will always be that JSON though, just the trips content and version will change

Comment: To answer your immediate question: no, if you intend to store `trips` as an embedded list in your DynamoDB item, then you cannot use fields within `trips` as your partition key or sort key. More broadly, the problem with trying to propose a schema for your table is that we don't have nearly enough information about how your client apps intend to access this data (what their query patterns are). Without that, you can't design the schema.

Comment: The design is  We are given this document, only one. The only thing that changes will be the items inside"trips". Then, I will get a request, and depending on the information of the request I will need to extract the information of one of the items in "trips".

Comment: That's just not enough information. How many trips will there be (approximately)? What uniquely distinguishes one trip from another, if anything? What kind of queries do you need to support (payment mode alone? type alone? payment mode plus type? all of the aforementioned? something else?) Is there any relationship between one trip and another, or are they independent?

Comment: independant. Just see them like a list of rules, I need to retreive one depending on the input I am given, like, given this payment Mode, and this type, tell me the payment amount it should be applied

Comment: OK, so the tuple of (paymentMode, type) is unique? And why is `locations` plural, yet contains only one name/payment. Should it be named `location` or should it actually be a list? What is the relevance of locations.name?

Comment: Ok, i added a new attribute to make it clear for you. The key should be a combination of: PaymentMode, type, and of of the companies. Right now i think the best option is to add an extra attribute where I append all this value in just one attribute, however, the list in company is bothering me, I don't know how to separate it (i will receive only 1 company in the request)

Answer (score 1):

When designing how to structure your data in a database, you need to consider A) what data you are storing B) how you will be accessing your data.

Additionally, you need to consider the characteristics of the database in questions. For DynamoDB, the main constraint is your primary key. The primary key is either the partition key or the combination of partition key and the sort key, and it must be unique for all items.

Although it's not entirely clear, based on your JSON your items are trips with fields `paymentMode`, `type` and `locations`. If those are your fields on the item, what should be your key? You mention using `paymentMode` and `type`, however, these likely won't be suitable, as they probably won't be unique. If you have a time associated with these, a primary key of `paymentMode_type` and sort key of time might do the job for you, but that depends on the volume of the data.

What you might be better off doing, is assign a unique identifier to each item (e.g. a `uuid`) and add secondary indices over the fields you want to use to query (`paymentMode`, `type`). This will allow you to query efficiently without having to scan the entire database. Do however keep in mind, that you will incur additional costs for the secondary indices.

Comment: My main doubt is, if I create a DB with key (payment mode + time), will they store correctly even if they are inside the field "trips"? if so, how should i define it, something like trips.paymentMode or directly paymentMode?

Comment: Are you saying that each item in your database has an array of trips?

Comment: nope. It is just this one document. With a variable length of trip items

Comment: Then the items within the trips field are your items in DynamoDB. You should not try to store a single item with an array of sub-documents

Comment: ok. The key should be a combination of 3 fields, should I create a key attribute and append all the data I need to retrieve it?

Comment: The way I usually do it is to keep all the original fields, but also create a composite field that is used as the primary key. So let's say you want to use `paymentMode` and `type`, the composite field would be called `paymentMode_type` and the values would be something like `ONLINE_A`. Obviously you'd have all three fields involved that you mentioned. And if you have a time value, or some other value that makes it unique, create a separate field and set that as the sort key